# Python selenium can't get data from a web browser javascript game

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybknI.png)I play this game with my little brother, and I want to make it harder as no one plays it and the AI in the game very easy. So I would make a bot/script to do this. I thought this would be easy with selenium webdriver. It can see all the data/text around the game, just not the game itself. If you inspect element you can see the data you need, like the question and the 4 multiple choices. But copying to xpath, does not work. Am I missing something? Any help here would be appreciated. The game is https://www.mathplayground.com/ASB_TugTeamMultiplication.html [Here is a picture of inspect element of the game. I circled the data I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K2Vh.png)

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","127.0.0.1:8989")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Coding\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=opt)


a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/g/g/g[9]/g[1]/g[1]/text[3]')

print(a)
```

This will print an error of nothing matching this xpath

Comment: Are you sure you have provided the correct URL or do we need to navigate to a particular game to find the xpath you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: I am new to selenium so I am not sure. That is the URL for the game. The data I need is visible in inspect element. Is there something I am missing? I found another url for the game in inspect element but that comes with same error that the xpath is incorrect.

Comment: added one at the top

Comment: The url you added does not show the element you want to capture. Could you add the exact URL where the element is present? Thanks

Comment: it is in the game itself, when you click play and start the game